# what does this operator do in ruby? <<=

Tags: ruby

I have some code that I am debugging that uses this operator and I'm not sure why it is used.

It appears to be appending the object to an array.  If that was all I do not know why the engineer didn't simply use the '<<' operator.  What is the difference?

Thanks!

Comment: An example of how it is used might help to give context.

Comment: Ask the engineer? It is slightly more expensive, and gives the same result (for arrays, for shift it may make sense as shift does not modify original value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm

it looks like its a bitwise left shift operation and assignment in one.

```
x <<= 2
```

is the same as

```
x = x << 2
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not always the case that `<<` modifies the target: it might be the result that is of importance. Consult the API for the actual types used as to the behavior.

A bit-shift of an integer does not have a side-effect (the computation is discarded unless it is assigned/used):

```
a = 1
a << 2
a # => 1
a <<= 2
a # => 4
```

But `<<` on an array *does* have a side-effect (and `<<=` would just perform a useless assignment<sup>1</sup> that hides the side-effect nature of the operation):

```
b = [1]
b << 2
b # => [1,2]
```

---

<sup>1</sup> In rare cases, it *might* be "clever" with accessors to use `obj.prop <<= val` for side-effecting operations as it will invoke *both* the getter and the setter - and the setter may contain logic. However, I use the word "clever" and not "good" here for a reason :)